# Java XML parsing validation with schema is not enabled

Tags: java, xml, validation, xml-parsing, schema

Trying to parse XML with schema validation:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setValidating(true);
dbf.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage",
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
db.parse(xmlFile)
```

Schema:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://xmlns.example.com/xml/example"
            xmlns:orm="http://xmlns.example.com/xml/example"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            version="1.0">
    <xsd:element name="book">
    <xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"
                         minOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string"
                         minOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

XML:

```
<book xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/xml/example"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.example.com/xml/example http://xmlns.example.com/xml/example/example.xsd">
   <name>Foo</name>
   <author>Bar</author>
   <hello>world</hello>      <----INVALID
</book>
```

But parsing without error. Is this the right way to enable schema validation while parsing DOM?

`http://java.sun.com`? very old domain?

Answer (score 0):

You do not set Schema of DocumentBuilderFactory. So DocumentBuilder can not validate. See javadoc for DocumentBuilderFactory setSchema method:
     * When a {@link Schema} is non-null, a parser will use a validator
     * created from it to validate documents before it passes information
     * down to the application.